# Return variable from AJAX for later processing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, global-variables

Due, to what it seems is a bug in the use of INNERHTML where my SELECT OPTION tag becomes blank(based on the research I have been able to do) - I'm having to try figure out how I can create a variable for later use that contains my OPTION tags based on the follow returned JSON data, and not having any joy;

```
[
{"saying":"Select a saying..."},
{"saying":"I rock the camera!"},
{"saying":"Ask me about Holland"},
{"saying":"I'm with the Photographer!"},
{"saying":"I'd love to frame you!"}
]
```

Below is my two core functions (Function loadlist & function ()), the latter is the one that will enable population of a select tag and passes parameters to the first that then gets the data from a mysql DB. {NOTE: the select tag works fine with the code I have today and if only within the body of the html file, it is only in the INNERHTML and using document.getElementById that it fails.

I have tried this on IE, FireFox, Safari and Chrome. Why am I doing this? I'm working to create a modal popup that contains many selectable options for a T-Shirt and based on those options guides you thru selecting sayings etc. and if INNERHTML would have worked I would have been done as it changes out the DIV's as expected other than my SELECT tag.

Working code:
......

```
<div id='target' class="target">
<p>in the div</p>
<p><select id="say1" name="say1" onchange="custom(this.id)" size="1"></select></p>
</div>
```

.......

Not Working code:
.........

```
    {
    div = document.getElementById('target'); 
    str = '<select id="say1" name="say1" onchange="custom(this.id)" size="1"></select>';
    div.innerHTML = str; 
    }
```

..............

```
/*function to load a list*/
function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr)
{


 $(selobj).empty();
    $.getJSON(url,{ data: 123, t: (new Date()).getTime() },function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,obj)
            {
                $(selobj).append(
                    $('<option></option>')
                        .val(obj[nameattr])
                        .html(obj[nameattr]));
            });
    });
}

    $(function()
    { 
       //By default, jQuery will load from cache if the request is same
       loadlist($('select#colour').get(0), 'getcolours.php?getlist=colour','colour');
       loadlist($('select#saying').get(0), 'getsaying.php?getlist=adultsaying','saying');
   loadlist($('select#say1').get(0), 'getsaying.php?getlist=adultsaying','saying');
    });
```

What would be helpful from the community is to show me where in my loadlist function I code up the ability to return the JSON data into a variable that can be later used, ideally adding the open and closing OPTION tags?

I'm a little new to some of this and the concepts are escaping me as is time I have to complete this project, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need atleast one option to make the onchange function working

```
 div = document.getElementById('target'); 
    str = '<select id="say1" name="say1" onchange="custom(this.id)" size="1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
    div.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: While that works in a static method it does not allow dynamic changes to the options. You will notice from the function loadlist that it will append an option list to the selected select. This code all works very well for in body HTML but not for appending to my str and then displaying it, so looking for the programmtic way to do this.